# Make a navbar shaped with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, frontend

Currently im trying to make a shaped Navigation Bar using bootstrap

[image]

currently this is my snippet

```
<div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <style>
          </style>
          <style>
            #nav-brand-bg{
              background-color: red;
              width: 100px;
              height: 100px;
              position: relative;
            }
          </style>
          <div id="nav-brand-bg"></div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="http://smarti-oc.dev/image/templates/smarti-new-logo.png" alt="">
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="http://smarti-oc.dev/image/templates/malaysia_resize.png" alt="">
          </a>
      </div>
```

is there any key, or a clue to make this one?
thanks a lot guys

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do you want to make the navbar shaped like the image?

Comment: yes, thats right.
have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab at...

```css
    #nav-brand-bg {
      background-color: red;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #navwrap {
      position: absolute;
      width: 90%;
    }
    
    #trapezoid {
      border-top: 100px solid black;
      border-left: 50px solid transparent;
      border-right: 50px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: skew(-27deg);
      -moz-transform: skew(-27deg);
      -o-transform: skew(-27deg);
      height: 0;
      width: 100px;
      left: -25px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #bar {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: black;
      height: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>

  <div id="nav-brand-bg"></div>
  <div id="navwrap">

    <div id="trapezoid">

    </div>
    <div id="bar">

    </div>
  </div>
```

This uses a different method, but as I couldn't see you images, does this look like what you are going for?

Comment: I was working on something similar to this with the trapezoid. Problem is the text won't stay within it.